# Mongodb find by many params is too slow

Tags: mongodb, find

I have mongo db over 6 mil documents,

it has over 20 params I have to search by, when I search by one field everything ok, problems start from searchin by 2 or more params, all params seted with indexes, but how can do it on multiply params, I understand that multiply indexes can help, but ther are too many indexes to cover all variants of params

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can only use a single index at a time when executing a query.

try to use `.explain()` to find which index was chosen. if you think another index should be used, you can guide the engine to use it.

about the `explain()` function:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain